# generate random number with fork()

Tags: c, random, process, fork, sleep

my program should have n child "process" , those child generate a random number between 1 and 9 every second, my problem is that  i should verify the child dont generate the same number in the same time

EXample if i have 5 child they can generate
    5  4  8  2  1
but they cant generate
    "5  5"  4  3  1

anyone can give me advice?

```
int main (int argc,char** argv)
{
    int i,pid,x,l;

    l=atoi(argv[1]);

    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        pid=fork();
        switch(pid)
        {
        case -1:
            printf("error\n");
        case 0: {
            srand(time(NULL));
            x=rand()%9+1;
            printf("Im child%d\n",x);sleep(1);
        }
        default:
            printf("Im parent %d\n",getpid());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you need random number generation, except you need it coordinated to avoid duplicates, yet you are generating the random numbers in separate processes which seem expressly designed to prevent the sort of coordination that you require?  What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: If this is to be done "every second" than there the numbers in 1..9 will be quickly taken. If a child (where there is <= 9 children) needs to create a unique number, just generate it in the parent (via an array shuffle) and pass it to the child (via "variable inheritance"?) to print :)

Comment: @JohnZwinck it seems logic that they dont generate the same number because rand() depend on time , but when i run the program they always  generate the same number

Comment: `rand()` does not depend on time in any way.

Comment: because i used srand(time()) ?

Comment: Also, you must use `break` for the `case`s.

Comment: @user2864740 i think i will try with the array thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your child processes need to communicate the random number they choose to the parent process. What you could do is use pipes to establish (2-way) communication between your parent and each child processes.

I insist on 2-way, because if the child draws a wrong number, the parent must ask again.

Here is some boilder-plate code I wrote a while ago, to establish such 2-way communication between parent and child process. What happens is that the parent writes to a file that happens to be the 'stdin' of the child, and the child writes to its stdout which is also read by the parent. Technicall it's in C++, but easy to adapt to C.

I don't understand what the possible use case of your random number generation in child processes. Perhaps you should be using **threads** instead of processes ?

```
#include "process.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

void Process::run(const char *cmd) throw (Err)
/*
 * Spawn a child process, and executes cmd. On success:
 * - pid is the process id
 * - in, out are FILE* to read/write from/to the process' stdout/stdin
 * */
{
    pid = 0;
    int readpipe[2], writepipe[2];
#define PARENT_READ     readpipe[0]
#define CHILD_WRITE     readpipe[1]
#define CHILD_READ      writepipe[0]
#define PARENT_WRITE    writepipe[1]

    try {
        if (pipe(readpipe) < 0 || pipe(writepipe) < 0)
            throw Err();

        pid = fork();

        if (pid == 0) {
            // in the child process
            close(PARENT_WRITE);
            close(PARENT_READ);

            if (dup2(CHILD_READ, STDIN_FILENO) == -1)
                throw Err();
            close(CHILD_READ);

            if (dup2(CHILD_WRITE, STDOUT_FILENO) == -1)
                throw Err();
            close(CHILD_WRITE);

            if (execlp(cmd, cmd, NULL) == -1)
                throw Err();
        } else if (pid > 0) {
            // in the parent process
            close(CHILD_READ);
            close(CHILD_WRITE);

            if ( !(in = fdopen(PARENT_READ, "r"))
                    || !(out = fdopen(PARENT_WRITE, "w")) )
                throw IOErr();
        } else
            // fork failed
            throw Err();
    } catch (Err &e) {
        cleanup();
        throw;
    }
}

void Process::cleanup()
{
    // close file descriptors
    if (in) fclose(in);
    if (out) fclose(out);

    // kill child process
    if (pid > 0) kill(pid, SIGKILL);
}

Process::~Process()
{
    cleanup();
}

void Process::write_line(const char *s) const throw(IOErr)
{
    fputs(s, out);
    fflush(out);    // don't forget to flush! (that's what she says)

    if (ferror(out))
        throw IOErr();
}

void Process::read_line(char *s, int n) const throw(IOErr)
{
    if (!fgets(s, n, in))
        throw IOErr();
}
```

Comment: Somehow I don't think that C++ code is going to help the OP get closer to addressing the true nature of his/her problem.

Comment: I'm new in c++ , but i will try to take an idea thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a cool problem because it simultaneously illustrates the fact that random number generation is in fact not random and the use and limitation of separate threads.

I'll simply note a few things.

1) You can not require that the random number that each child process picks must be coordinated with the other processes for 2 reasons.  1) They would not be picking random numbers any more, they would be selecting a number that another process has not already picked; that's random?  2) If all child process have to coordinate with the parent process, then the overall process will be slower than if there was only 1 process -- in other words useless, but maybe that's the point of the exercise.  That is, allow the overall algorithm to not be fast and efficient, but increase the randomness by including a "process scheduling" factor.  If not then keep reading.

2) Can each process run at full speed, or must each process wait until all other process as finished with the current iteration?  Or can the parent process simply record each child's pick at time slot n?

3) There can't be more than 9 child processes because you'd be guaranteed that at lest 2 would pick the same number.

So, can each child seed the "pseudo random number generator" with the same seed and then add their number to it mod 9?  It's random in that it's a pseudo random number plus a constant.  The only drawback is that it's not random w.r.t. the other children, but then let's say you don't like that, then we're back to observation #1, it's slower and it's still not random w.r.t. the other children because it's coordinated.  It's no less random otherwise because rnd() is in fact deterministic, it just appears to be random.

Update (some pseudo code):

```
In the parent process
   select a seed number S

   for index = 0 .. numChildren - 1 do
      fork child
      childNum = index
      communicate(S,childNum) to child

   while true
      receive(childRND,childNum,childIteration) from child
      iterationResults[childIteration,childNum] = childRND
      iterationResults[childIteration].numResults++
      if(iterationResults[childIteration].numResults == numChildren) then
         print iterationResults[childIteration]
         delete iterationResults[childIteration]
```

The child pseudocode:

```
In each child process
   Seed the random number generator with S
   for iteration = 1 ... do
      X = RND(1,9)
      Y = RND(1,10000)
      Pick the Yth number N that is relatively prime to 9 (or just pick the Yth prime)
      childRND = (X + (Y*childNum mod 9)) mod 9 + 1
      send(childRND,childNum,iteration) to parent
```

Notes:

Since all children seed the RNG with the same seed S, they X and Y will always be the same number for each child.

Because Y is relatively prime to 9, N*Y mod 9 where N = 0..8 will create a permutation of the numbers 0..8.  Since we select a "random" Y, the permutation will also be "random" and so (X + (Y*childNum mod 9)) mod 9  + 1 will scrambled each new iteration, however each child is guaranteed to return a different number than the other children.

Yes, this is still deterministic, but the reported result will appear much more randomish.